# How can I change Media Information in VLC Media Player?

Tags: vlc-media-player

OK, it's under Tools | Media Information. But there doesn't seem to be a way to save the modified file. When I select Media | Convert/Save and save the file as a new file that new file is empty. (I wouldn't expect it to save the modified Media Information anyway, if its input seems to be the file on disk.)

So how can I save a file whose Media Information has been changed?

(BTW, the file's format is .m4v)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, and it appears I don't need any video player or editor at all.
In Windows Explorer, right click the file and click Properties.

[image]

In the Properties dialog, select the Details tab, and there you can enter the same info which shows in VLC's Media Information.